# Обращение к comboBox в потоке

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь получить текст из combobox, но увы появляется ошибка, что доступ не из того потока в котором он был создан.

Как это обойти и, что делать.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    System.Threading.Thread myThread = new System.Threading.Thread(get_list_id);
    myThread.Start();

}
void get_list_id() {
    var tarakan = comboBox1.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    comboBox1.Invoke(new Action(get_list_id));       
}

void get_list_id()
{
    string tarakan = comboBox1.Text;
}
```

Comment: @DreamChild Благодарю, всё работает, а в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: @MadKeks универсальность почти всегда лучше и элегантнее. И да, универсальный рецепт дал вам не я, а @VladD

Comment: @DreamChild: Ну, у меня по существу ваш код, просто обёрнут в функцию. Добавил лишь проверку `InvokeRequired` для универсальности.

Answer (score 1):

Можно даже универсальное решение сделать. Наподобие:

```
public T Get<T>(Func<T> getter)
{
    if (!InvokeRequired())
        return getter();
    T t = default(T);
    Invoke((Action)(() => { t = getter(); }));
    return t;
}

...
string tarakan = Get(() => comboBox1.Text);
```